# Comparing Population Pyramid - Fixed or dynamic X-axis?

Tags: graph, chart, population

I have prepared an [interactive visualization](http://www.cartoskill.com/Interactive/PopulationPyramid.html) for Population Pyramid of G-20 countries from 1990 to 2100 using United Nations 2015 Revision of World Population Prospects data.

However, in order to compare I started with fixed X-axis. But some countries with less population, like Germany, Italy, Japan, etc. are almost not visible if the axis is fixed based on World population.

[image: Fixed Axis]

On the other hand with dynamic axis, based on individual country's highest population, although each pyramid is visible, the size is not comparable.

[image: Dynamic Axis]

I would like get some advice/suggestion about the right choice.

Comment: You had a cartography tag but there seems to be no map involved in your question so I'm removing it. Also, there seems to be no GIS component to what appears to be a graphing question so I am thinking that it may be better asked at [su].

Comment: basically it depends on what you want to compare, demographic states/stages of countries in which case use dynamic, or absolute population trends in which case fixed